# Replacing first occurrence of many substrings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to (using Javascript) replace the *first* occurrence of *many* substrings with other substrings that *may contain a mixture* of the original substrings. I think it's probably simplest to just show an example.

### An example of what I want to do

Suppose I have a map

```js
const MAP = {
  "dog": "big dog",
  "big": "huge",
  "cat": "mouse"
}
```

and a paragraph

```html
<p id="paragraph">I have a dog, a big cat, another dog, and another big cat.</p>
```

After the window is loaded, I'd like to change this to

```html
<p id="paragraph">I have a big dog, a huge mouse, another dog, and another big cat.</p>
```

### My attempts

One way to almost do this, is the following:

```js
var p = document.getElementById('paragraph');
window.onload = function() {
  var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(MAP).join("|"), "gi");
  p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(re, function(match) {return MAP[match];});
}
```

But this returns `I have a big dog, a huge mouse, another big dog, and another huge mouse.` This is not surprising because the `g` tag ensures that all occurrences are replaced, whereas I only want the first occurrence.

So then my second attempt is the following:

```js
var p = document.getElementById('paragraph');
var l = Object.keys(MAP);

window.onload = function() {
  for(var j=0; j<l.length; j++) {
    p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(l[j], MAP[l[j]]);
  }
}
```

But this returns `I have a huge dog, a big mouse, and another dog, and another big cat.` That's because `dog` has been replaced by `big dog`, and then that `big` gets replaced with `huge` instead of the `big` before `cat`.

### Summary

How can I non-iteratively replace the first occurrence of multiple substrings in a string? This seems like the sort of thing that has probably been asked before on this site, but I haven't been able to find it anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's split the string into two parts: already processed (left) and not processed yet (right). On each step, locate one of search strings in the right part and take the one that comes first. Add the slice before the keyword and the replacement to the left part. Slice the right part from after the search. Repeat until no search string can be found

```js
function replace(str, map) {
    let searches = new Set(Object.keys(map))
    let left = '', right = str

    while (1) {
        let pos = Infinity, search = ''

        for (let s of searches) {
            let i = right.indexOf(s)
            if (i >= 0 && i < pos) {
                pos = i;
                search = s;
            }
        }

        if (!search)
            break

        left += right.slice(0, pos) + map[search]
        right = right.slice(pos + search.length)

        searches.delete(search)
    }

    return left + right
}

//

const MAP = {
  "dog": "big dog",
  "big": "huge",
  "cat": "mouse"
}

text = "I have a dog, a big cat, another dog, and another big cat."

console.log(replace(text, MAP))
```

and here's a simpler solution with regular expressions:

```js
function replace(str, map) {
    let used = new Set,
        re = new RegExp(Object.keys(map).join('|'), 'g')
    return str.replace(re, m => {
        if (used.has(m))
            return m
        used.add(m)
        return map[m]
    })
}

//

const MAP = {
    "dog": "big dog",
    "big": "huge",
    "cat": "mouse"
}

text = "I have a dog, a big cat, another dog, and another big cat."

console.log(replace(text, MAP))
```

or, if you like "compressed" code,

```
let replace = (str, map, used = {}) => str.replace(
    new RegExp(Object.keys(map).join('|'), 'g'),
    m => used[m] ? m : map[used[m] = m])
```

Comment: I admit I do like the compressed solution best :) thanks a lot this works great!

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to replace only the first matches, I think the best way is to prepare the string with some placeholder texts and then make the replacements. I don't like the idea of running the same loop twice, but there is no other way to prepare the string.

```js
const MAP = {
  "dog": "big dog",
  "big": "huge",
  "cat": "mouse"
}

const p = document.querySelector("p");

let t = p.innerText;

Object.keys(MAP).forEach(x => {
 let parts = t.split(x);
 t = `${parts.shift()}%%${x.toUpperCase()}%%${parts.join(`${x}`)}`;
});

Object.keys(MAP).forEach(x => {
  t = t.replace(`%%${x.toUpperCase()}%%`, MAP[x]);
})

console.log(t)

p.innerText = t;

//<p id="paragraph">I have a big dog, a huge mouse, another dog, and another big cat.</p>
```

```html
<p id="paragraph">I have a dog, a big cat, another dog, and another big cat.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a `for(... in ...)` loop since replace works by default only for the first match. For not replacing twice (f.e. `big` from `big dog`) you can use two auxiliary vars: one for building the new string (`newP`) and one for replacing the words (`tempP`).

After replacing the words you have to update the original string (`paragraph`) by removing the first part including the word(s). This can be done for example with `slice()`. After that you just have to add the removed part to the new string.

After the for loop you can simply insert the new string and the rest of the original string into the paragraph with `innerHTML`.

**Working example**:

```js
const MAP = {
  "dog": "big dog",
  "big": "huge",
  "cat": "mouse"
}
let newP = '';

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let paragraph = document.getElementById('paragraph').textContent;
  for(let key in MAP) {
    let tempP = paragraph.replace(key, MAP[key]);
    paragraph = tempP.slice(tempP.indexOf(MAP[key]) + MAP[key].length);
    newP += tempP.slice(0, tempP.indexOf(MAP[key]) + MAP[key].length);
  }
  document.getElementById('paragraph').innerHTML = newP + paragraph;
});
```

```html
<p id="paragraph">I have a dog, a big cat, another dog, and another big cat.</p>
```